# How to put String list in SQL database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an edittext that allows the user to enter in numbers up to 10.

I want to be able to save this numbers to a SQLite database as a String list.

Does SQL allow this to be done? If so how?

Such as 
    String [] list = {1020300303,1020303001,0102003020};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, but you'll be breaking normalization rules.

If you persist that array as a single string (comma-delimited?), you'll have to parse it to look at individual values.  Not a good idea.

A normalized schema would use a one-to-many relationship between two tables.  One would be the parent, the other the child with one row per value and a primary/foreign key relationship.  You'd get the values back using a JOIN.

If you're so intent on doing this, you'll have to concatenate all the Strings in the array into one, with some delimiter in between them that you're sure will never appear in any of the Strings you're combining.  Once you have a single delimited String, INSERT it into a String-type column in a table in your SQLite database.

Since you insist on seeing some code, here's what it might look like in Java:

```
String [] list = { "1020300303", "1020303001", "0102003020" };
StringBuilder concatenatedList = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : list) {
    concatenatedList.append(s).append('~'); // Any delimiter will do.
}
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MySQLiteTable(stringColumnName) VALUES(?)";
ps.setString(1, concatenatedList.toString());
int numRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
```

I wouldn't write it this way - no cleanup, no error handling, no good encapsulation.  But it shows where you want to go.

Comment: Coudld you explain more with code? And what if i had 10 columns like number 1,number2, ect. and pulls the numbers like that? Since the user is limited to 10 numbers? Or would this be over-kill? I thought the way above would be the most efficient.

Comment: Or maybe there is another way i can do this other than SQLite

Comment: What if they have fewer than ten?  Would you ever be interested in knowing how many numbers they entered?  A simple COUNT query would tell you that.  Your way would mean query to string, split it into an array, and get the length of the array.  What if they remove just one value?  Your way is a b!tch; a normalized approach just removes the row from the child WHERE VALUE = (removed value).  My advice holds for all relational databases, not just SQLite.

Comment: Okay so.... All i want to do is put the String[] into a database..and then pull the list out when needed..

Comment: So go ahead...what's stopping you?  Concatenate the Strings into one, with some delimiter between them, and INSERT away.  It's your funeral.

Comment: Nothing - why do you need so much approval?  I already gave you the technical reason - normalization.  What else do you want?

Comment: Could you show me code for when you said "So go ahead...what's stopping you? Concatenate the Strings into one, with some delimiter between them, and INSERT away. It's your funeral" ?

Comment: How would i concatenate them and then delimiter between them?

Comment: Why do i need the delimiter if the user is required or it will only work if the user enter's commas betwween each phone number?

Comment: So wouldnt the delimiter all ready be there? Or i may be wrong?

Comment: You sure are needy.  Figure it out, dude.

Comment: Come on man... I accepted the answer for you. Im sure you can answer this small LAST part of the question.

Comment: I think I've already spent far too much time on your question.  Figure - it - out.